# How can I use FullSimplify output in function construction without having to re-FullSimplify? (Doubts about my workaround)

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, caching

I have an expression that I want to use in a function definition. For concreteness let's take `Gamma[k + 4]/k!`. I know this can be simplified to `(1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + k)`, but I don't want to have to copy-paste the simplified expression into my function definion like this

```
copypaste[k_] := (1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + k)
```

so instead I write

```
slow[k_] := FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]
```

This second function is not only slow, but Mathematica will redo the simplification each time I want to evaluate this function.

**Solution so far**

A way to solve this is to use

```
evaluated[k_] = FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]
simplerandfaster[k_] := evaluated[k]
```

This works, but it feels like a not-so-neat workaround to me. If I have to do this trick several times for different functions in one notebook I'll have a bunch of function names like `evaluated` which I will only ever use once. **Is there a better way?** I guess I could add `ClearAll@evaluated` at the end or put everything inside a `Module` block, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: I would use `Pochhammer[k + 1, 3]` instead.

Comment: In a notebook, you can use evaluate-in-place as well. Just select the bit of code you want to evaluate (so `FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]`) and then hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Other than that, `evaluated[k_] = FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]` is the idiomatic way to do it. If you want to be on the same side, put `Block[{k}, ...]` around it. There's no need for `simplerandfaster[k_] := evaluated[k]` either, it doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us see. This

```
slow[k_] := FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!];
AbsoluteTiming[slow[n]]

(*  {0.0000689, (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n)}  *)
```

yields the timing 6.9 10^-5 s.
This is a ten times faster:

```
faster[k_] := Evaluate[FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]];
AbsoluteTiming[faster[n]]

(*  {5.7*10^-6, (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n)}  *)
```

yielding 5.7 10^-6 s.

This is approximately the same

```
faster2[k_] = FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!];
AbsoluteTiming[faster2[n]]

(*  {6.*10^-6, (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n)}   *)
```

This

```
copypaste[k_] := (1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + k);
AbsoluteTiming[copypaste[n]]
```

(* {9.4*10^-6, (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n)} *)

also yields about 10^-5.

My conclusion is that the second and third methods are equally fast and are the best that I can offer.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Alexei's answer:

```
In[645]:= Clear[slow];
slow[k_] := Evaluate[FullSimplify[Gamma[k + 4]/k!]]

In[647]:= DownValues[slow]

Out[647]= {HoldPattern[slow[k_]] :> (1 + k) (2 + k) (3 + k)}
```